# Trying to get the JavaScript variable scope correct in this trello.get code

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, trello

I have been struggling to set the variable 'listName' scope correct in this code ...

```
var loadedAtriskopps = function(opps) {
    var listName = 'empty';
    $.each(opps.cards, function(index, opp) {
        Trello.get(
            '/cards/' + opp.id + '/list?fields=name', {fields: "id, name"}, function(list, err) {
                var listName = list.name;
                console.log(listName); //this returns the correct value
            });
        console.log(listName); //this returns 'empty'
        var opp = $("<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6'><p class='output'>" + opp.name + "</b><br>On List: " + listName + " </p></div>    </div>");
        $('#opps').append(opp)
    });
};
```

Inside the Trello.get function it returns correctly, but not outside of it. After hours of research, still cannot get it right.

---

UPDATE:

Per the recommendation, tried this code:

```
 var loadedAtriskopps = function(opps) {
    var listName = 'empty';
    $.each(opps.cards, function(index, opp) {
        console.log(opp.name); // returns correct value
        Trello.get('/cards/' + opp.id + '/list?fields=name', {fields: "id, name"})
              .success(function(list) {
                listName = list.name;
                console.log(listName); // // returns correct value
                // next line errors "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" but listName is correct
                var opp = $("<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6'><p class='output'>" + opp.name + "</b><br>On List: " + listName + " </p></div>    </div>");
                $('#opps').append(opp);
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                console.log("An error: " + err);
              });
    });
};
```

Seems I have lost definition for the `opp` object with in the success callback.

---

SOLUTION:

```
 var loadedAtriskopps = function(opps) {
    var listName = 'empty';
    $.each(opps.cards, function(index, opp) {
        Trello.get('/cards/' + opp.id + '/list?fields=name', {fields: "id, name"})
              .success(function(list) {
                listName = list.name;
                var card = $("<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6'><p class='output'>" + opp.name + "</b><br>On List: " + listName + " </p></div>    </div>");
                $('#opps').append(card);
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                console.log("An error: " + err);
              });
    });
};
```

Thank you Darren and Andy!

Comment: You're re assigning the opp object in the success - change `var opp` to `var somethingelse` then `$('#opps').append(somethingelse);` - why do you want to use the same name?

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the assist, @DarrenSweeney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to move your post-ajax operations into a success callback. This should ensure you have the actual value *after* the ajax has the value of `listName`.

```
var loadedAtriskopps = function(opps) {
    var listName = 'empty';
    $.each(opps.cards, function(index, opp) {
        Trello.get('/cards/' + opp.id + '/list?fields=name', {fields: "id, name"})
              .success(function(list) {
                listName = list.name;
                console.log(listName); // should return correct value
                var _opp = $("<div class='row'><div class='col-xs-6'><p class='output'>" + opp.name + "</b><br>On List: " + listName + " </p></div>    </div>");
                $('#opps').append(_opp);
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                console.log("An error: " + err);
              });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I removed the `var` on the nested `listName` as you suggested and have the same result as before.

Comment: Bryan, it looks like you'll have to add a success callback for your ajax call. When you `console.log(listName)` outside the `.get()`, it's empty because the ajax needs to finish. I'll update the answer a bit.

Comment: I updated the original question with the code as you described. Seems like I have lost definition for the `opp` object within the success callback.

Comment: Without a way to test the live code, it's difficult to help you with 100% confidence. Can you put a little demo up somewhere?

Comment: Darren pointed out that using `opp` as a variable twice in the success callback was the problem. Really appreciate your help! Struggled with this for hours.

Comment: No problem. In the answer, I changed the duplicate `opp` to `_opp`, so that it will correctly work.